# Want to send one particular field into csv file using logstash?

Tags: csv, logstash

Instead of removing all the other fields using remove_field can i send the required field(i.e source_query) only to csv.If it is done may i know how it can be done?

```
        input {
          file {
            path => "C:\elasticsearch-2.4.1\sir.log"
            start_position => "beginning"
          }
        }

        filter {
           grok {
                match => [ "message",source\[%{DATA:source_query}\]]
           }

  }
    }
        output {
           csv {
              fields => ["source_query"]
              path => "C:\logstash\logstash-2.4.0\bin\source.csv"

           }
        stdout { codec => rubydebug }

        }
```

Comment: What problem are you having with that?  It should work as is unless you are using an old version of logstash.

Comment: Your problem may be your use of windows style paths.  Change all of the \ to /

Comment: The code is working fine, but i want to know is there any other mutate feature in logstash so that instead of removing the other fields i can able to send the required field(i.e `source_query`) directly to csv.

Comment: just remove the mutate... the fields => in the csv output should be all you need.  the stdout won't have the same output as the csv file

Comment: Thankyou it worked, but i also wanted to know if suppose it is other than csv format, then to pass a particular field then again i have to choose mutate field only right..In that which feature i have to select to send particular field to output(i.e add_field something like that)

Answer (score 0):

To work with any output, you can use the [prune filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-prune.html)

For example:

```
filter {
  prune {
    whitelist_names => ["source_query"]
  }
}
```